# How to remove very thin light and dark edges on navigation bar

Tags: css

One of my clients noticed a very thin light line and a very thin dark line in the active link on their navigation bar. It's barely noticeable, but it's there. I've tried tweaking the CSS, but since the lines are less than a pixel wide, I'm not sure that it's the CSS.

Here's the url: http://www.abqlibraryfoundation.org

If you look at the "Home" link in the navigation bar, you'll see that as the active page, it's a rusty orange color and it has a thin light edge on the left side. The right side has a dark thin edge in between the orange and turquoise colors.

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: If you hadn't pointed it out very specifically, I would never have noticed it.

Comment: I believe it's because it's a screen and not a printed piece of paper. I would guess it's because it's anti-aliased and not falling on an exact pixel on the screen. If you tweaked the orange/blue to not be so similar in their grey values, I bet it might go away.

Comment: Man, I don't miss my days of doing web development contract work.  Some clients can be a PITA

Comment: It could be a trick of the eye or a technical issue with rendering.  Screenshot the photo, put it into Photoshop and zoom all the way in.  There's no border or anything.  Also note, the left side appear to have a "white" like line on it.  On a side note, you can still "see" the artifact in Photoshop but appears exactly the same no matter how close you get.

Comment: Yeah and the Donate button has rough edges.  It's pixels. You actually might be able to get rid of it if you use an image/sprite for your nav, but it's not worth it.

Comment: It looks like a display artifact to me, a consequence of the chosen colors and the way they are rendered on an LCD monitor.  If you increase the zoom to the maximum possible size, you will see that the lines stay the same width.  Happens in every browser on my machine.

Comment: You could try to alter the blue/orange a bit just to see if it goes away. Make one of them darker/lighter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of **sub-pixel artifacts**.

It is used also constructively nowadays to smooth text. This is because the screen is composed of red, green and blue sub-pixels, disposed in a vertical orientation. Note that the actual order may differ on some screens.

```
rgb|rgb|rgb
---+---+---
rgb|rgb|rgb
---+---+---
rgb|rgb|rgb
```

This means that in the navigation bar you have a disposition like the following:

```
blue       |    red    |   blue
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
  b|  b|  b|r  |r  |r  |  b|  b
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
  b|  b|  b|r  |r  |r  |  b|  b
           ^           ^
           |           Artifact caused by sub-pixels being far away (darker line)
           |
           Artifact caused by vicinity of sub-pixels (lighter line)
```

I have also created an image illustrating the typical pixel disposition in an lcd screen (rgb):

[image: Sub-Pixel artifacts]

you can see how on the first *transition*, when changing blue to orange, there is a green subpixel followed by a blue and by a red one, which are **relatively close** to each other. Our eye **perceives this as white**.

On the right (the second transition from orange to blue), shows a gap giving the illusion of a dark color.

### A note on mobile devices

Since most webpages on mobile devices are usually **scaled**, this effect is far less noticeable (due to image resampling). Anouther aspect to consider is that the **orientation of the screen** can be changed, and thus possibly creating artifacts in different directions.

If you are interested in how this effects are leveraged to render smooth text, you can continue reading the following article on wikipedia: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering)

This is how screen work nowadays, nothing you can do about (without changing the design)

Comment: Ok, at least now I can tell my client what the issue is. BTW, I tried changing the rusty orange color to a variety of colors, and as predicted some colors looked fine and some colors not. Thanks to all for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing a white line, it's a defect of your monitor or an optical illusion.  Here's a blown-up screenshot from chrome.  As you can clearly see in the expanded section, there is no column of lighter pixels.

[image: screenshot]

By trial and error, I find that I can eliminate the illusion *on my monitor* by applying this style.

```
.nav-bar>li#active>a{ border-left: rgb(146, 108, 66) 1px solid; }
```

It creates a 1 pixel darker orange at the left edge and ends up looking like this.  If you zoom in on that one, it ends up looking noticeably worse than the original.

[image]